# Translation of 覚えちゃうくらいの距離で

Tags: translation, meaning, words

Recently I was listing a youtube video and I found a song that blew my mind. I can understand almost every word, but no matter how hard I try, I can't understand the construction: 覚えちゃうくらいの距離で. 
If you could, explain me the use of ちゃう and くらい because I think the definitions I have of them are not correct. I really appreciate any help you can give to me. Thank you!

Lyrics.

> キミの体温感じてる　いつも口ずさむあのメロディー
>   覚えちゃうくらいのキョリで　同じごはん食べてても
>   どうしてこうも違うのかな　今は何考えてるの？
>
> この部屋にひとりは広すぎるみたい
>   ねえ早く帰ってきて　My Sweet Prince
>
> ふたりのセカイ　ふたりのミライ
>   一生のお願いはイラナイから
>
> 溢れる想い　溺れそうになったら
>   わたしがそこから救い出してあげるから
>
> いつかおそろいで買った　色違いのクッション抱いて
>   寝てるキミを抱きしめる　ベッドははんぶんこ
>   ずっとぎゅっとくっついてたら　同じ夢まで見ちゃうかもね
>
> 「このままセカイが終わりませんように」
>   「このセカイがずっとずっと続きますように」　願うの
>
> 思うだけじゃ伝わらなくて　声に出さないとわからなくて
>   もどかしくて　わかってほしくて　無理しちゃって　ケンカもして
>   離れてって　寂しくて　苦しくって　泣いちゃって
>   それでもずっと一緒にいたいの　好きだから
>
> ふたりのセカイ　ふたりのミライ
>   一生のお願いはイラナイから
>
> 溢れる想い　溺れそうになったら
>   わたしがそこから救い出してあげるから
>
> キミのこと守るから

Comment: Are you sure "覚えちゃうくらいの距離で" is correct? I don't see those lyrics anywhere online. I could try to explain like that but it would be best if you give more context (a few lines before it and after).

Comment: yes it is. The song is twinkle world 初音ミク.

Answer (score 3):

覚えちゃう is short form of 覚えてしまう, where 〜てしまう means something is funny, exaggerated, accidental, or some other type of emphasis.

くらい here means "the amount" or "to the extent"

UPDATE: The explanation I had here was wrong, which was pointed about by user naruto. So I am re-writing it based on his suggestion which I agree with.

Here 覚える simply means "to remember" or even "memorize", and the connotation is that the melody referred to in the previous line is at such a distance (= so close) that the person hearing it will memorize it.

> 覚えちゃうくらいの距離で
>
> Literal: At a distance such that I remember it
>
> Non-literal (but more natural): So close that it sticks in my head

Comment: いや、この「覚える」は単純に「キミの口ずさむメロディーを記憶してしまうくらいの距離」の意味だと思います。「体温」には既に「感じている」という別の動詞が対応していますし。

Comment: Ok, you are translating 距離 as close? I thought it means distance or far I did not know it also means close. Am I correct?.

Comment: Yes, 距離 is literally "distance", but I translated "close" because it is implied here. I just edited my post significantly, please check out the result.

Comment: @naruto: thanks for pointing that out! I just re-wrote my answer

Comment: @user15855 See: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29453/5010

Comment: @naruto Does くらい have different meaning according the context it is in? GOD DAMN IT! I don't get it! it's soo frustrating. naruto could you explain me this slowly? please?

Comment: @user15855 Maybe this will help? http://maggiesensei.com/2011/01/26/request-lesson-%E4%BD%8D-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%EF%BC%8F%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-kuraigurai/

Comment: @Blavius Thank you A LOT!!  I get it now!!