# Could someone clarify the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: meaning, multiple-readings

I'm having some problems with a few pieces of a script I'm reading. These are the following phrases:

"こうであってほしいっていう願望は別でもいいでしょう？" : context for this one is that someone was asked what they thought about a certain topic. I would interpret it as "Wishing for things to be like this doesn't really matter, right?", but I'm not really sure.

and

"慣れない嘘つくくらい特別な着信があったってことなのか" : context for this is one of the guys is being teased for telling an obvious lie about recieving a message from someone. But I can't really decide how to interpret this, something along the lines of "Telling such an obvious lie when you have a special ringtone for it".

EDIT: Adding context for the last phrase, since it's not clear just by looking at it: A group of friends gather together and only one of them recieves a text from a mutual friend of the group, so the other ones start teasing him about it.

Lastly, what would be an acceptable translation for "実際としても" or 実際する in general.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking their time to review this.

Comment: You answer to this might be unusually long because this question has not one, but three questions in it.  I would suggest splitting it into three questions.  Additionally, when asking for translation help, it's best to include your attempt to avoid getting the question closed as off-topic.

Comment: My attempts are right there, for both of the phrases giving me trouble. The only one is just a matter of usage, so I didn't include anything but I will if it's required, of course.

Comment: Could you edit out two of the questions and post them separately? It would also be appreciated if each question had a specific title to help future users find them.  Please ask one question per question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> こうであってほしいっていう願望は別でもいいでしょう？

You've missed the meaning of 別 ("different", "another") here. 願望は別でもいいでしょう means "A wish can be different (from something), right?" or "It's okay to have another wish, isn't it?" こうであってほしいっていう modifies 願望. More context is needed, but I guess the speaker is saying that you can at least wish whatever you want (although understanding the reality is also important).

**別に**いいでしょう would mean "It doesn't really matter, does it?"

> 慣れない嘘つくくらい特別な着信があったってことなのか

You've missed the `AくらいB` construction, which means "B to the extent that A", "B to the point where A", "so B that A", "such B that A". So 慣れない嘘つくくらい特別な着信があった means "there was such a special phone call that you had to tell an awkward lie".

- [The difference between くらい and ほど in hyperbole](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2392/5010)
- [Postpositional or prepositional くらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29453/5010)
- [Learn JLPT N3 Grammar: くらい (kurai)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-kurai/)

> 実際**と**しても

実際としても usually means "practically speaking" or "(also) in a practical perspective". 実際する makes no sense because 実際 is not a suru-verb.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, and I will be reviewing the links you've provided for a more indepth read on the subject.

Comment: @FedeBusso Next time please avoid asking more than one thing in a question. And please consider including some more context (actually the second sentence makes little sense to me in isolation...)

Comment: Of course, I'm not used to using these sites so please excuse the lack of context for it. For what is worth, the context is as follows:
a group of friends gather together and only one of them recieves a text from a mutual friend of the group, so the other ones start teasing him about it.