# The meaning of 昔から『勘と運』だけは自覚出来るくらいいい in this context (MC's thought about his intuition and luck )

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english

**When reading , I don't understand this sentence "昔から『勘と運』だけは自覚出来るくらいいい"**

**Much thanks if anyone can help me understand correctly its meaning.
(my guess but not sure : "At least since I was still a kid, I have a good self-aware about my intuition and luck." ??)**

Context: Since he was still a kid, MC felt that he's a lucky boy (he had won many lotteries in the past based purely on his luck). Currently his parent is traveling around the world, after he just won a special lottery prize ,which is a world travel trip for 2 persons in 3 months.

But now when he's staying at home and laying down on his bed in the evening, he has a bad feeling/ premonition that something bad/ serious is about to happens. (he's also living with his big sisters at home, so I don't know if he meant "something bad is about to happens" for his big sisters, or for him, or for his parents.)

MC「父さん達が帰って来るまでの３ヶ月の間、姉さん達と何事もなく過ごせればいいんだけど。こんな調子だと先が思いやられそうだ」

ぼそりと呟きながら、ベッドの上に寝転び、天井を見つめる。

あえて口にしたのは、漠然とした不安があるからだ。

父さん達がいない間に何か大変なことが起こるかもしれない。

そんな予感っていうか、胸騒ぎがする。

悪い癖だと思うけど、**昔から『勘と運』だけは自覚出来るくらいいい。**

MC「だから、何か起こりそうで不安なんだよなぁ。今朝の夢のことも気になるし……」

MC「ふぅ、やめやめ、姉さん達が頑張ってるのに俺がこんなこと考えていたらだめだろ」

Comment: Is it from a published book, and if so, what is the title and/or the author? The larger context and genre might help, and if nothing else, a proper attribution is nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation attempt is okay overall, but 自覚できるくらい is an adverbial phrase that modifies いい. See:  [Postpositional or prepositional くらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29453/5010)

> 昔から『勘と運』だけは自覚出来るくらいいい。
>
> Ever since I was a kid, I have at least good luck and intuition to the point where I can be aware of them.

Comment: I'm still not quite understand what he wanted to says here ...

Comment: @casualreader How about "I am lucky enough to realize I am a lucky man."?