# What is the meaning of くらい in 優しいくらいなんだ?

Tags: grammar, particle-くらい

A guy walking with his girl produced the following inner monologue, commenting on how nice she is.

> 付き合ってること親に黙っててくれてるってだけで...優しいくらいなんだ

I am uncertain about the meaning of くらい after 優しい. I am wondering if this definition is relevant here:

> ②ある事柄を示し，その程度が軽いもの，弱いものとして表す。「酒―飲んだっていいよ」「ご飯―たけるよ」

I don't think [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96580/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e6%83%9c%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f%e3%82%89%e3%81%84) is relevant here because this くらい is different and I don't see any relevant verb or adjectives that go with くらい.

Comment: [More context please](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010).

Comment: @naruto I am not sure what else you need to know. There is nothing before and after.

Comment: Please read the link, and copy several sentences before this. This is not a type of sentence uttered without context; it is fairly puzzling if interpreted in isolation.

Comment: @naruto Here is the manga panel that contains the sentence in question: [彼女、お借りします-263話](https://imgur.com/a/XjWMft0). I am not sure if you are familiar with the story. I modified the sentence in the first place because I thought it will be a bother to explain the whole story...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>(I had to use my マガポケ to read the entire chapter for the full context. The key context is that the girl is basically a troublemaker and he was skeptical of her personality and intent. Otherwise, the sentence in question makes little sense.)</sup>

You probably have no problem reading this:

> 納豆は毎日食べたい**くらい**おいしい。
> ∼ 納豆はおいしくて、毎日食べたい**くらい**だ。
> Natto is so delicious that I (even) want to eat it every day.
> Natto is delicious to the point where I want to eat it every day.

In this construction, the part before くらい is a (surprising/extreme) result/conclusion based on the associated reason (おいしい). The reason part is typically a simple adjective like おいしい, but in your case, it's a long clause (黙ってくれてる).

> 現状、水原のこと事務所とかに黙ってくれてるってだけで優しい**くらい**なんだ。
> For now, she (Mami) keeps the secret about Mizuhara from the office, and for this (reason) alone, **I'd rather/even say** she's kind.

黙ってくれてる is the reason, and 優しい is the (surprising) result (which he has to admit). The guy (Kazuya) emphasized 優しい with くらい because, up to this point, he had been so nervous and suspicious of the intent of his ex-girlfriend (Mami). While walking together, he started to convince himself that she was not that evil.

Comment: Thank you, can I also understand this くらい as a surprising result of 怒らない?

Answer (score -2):

I think it means "like". Yasahii is an adjective. so here by saying "kurai" he is saying "it's really nice actually". so if I am translating this phrase correctly in my mind he is saying. "if my parents could  just shut up about me dating, it would be nice of them wouldn´t it?"