# What does たい+くらいだもんな mean?

Tags: sentence, questions, particle-くらい

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> 人煽るのはそんなに楽しいか

"Is that fun to instigate people?"

"Despite the fact people attempt to be kind/attempt to things kindly/etc"

> まあそんなの必要ねえか

"Well that is not necessary"

> 俺に相手にされてえくらいだもんな?

My understanding is that is read as

俺に相手にされてたいくらいだもんな?

> 俺を怒らせてえんだろーが

"You wanted to make me mad, right?"

So akin to "You want me to be your partner/pay attention to you/take notice"? How is くらいだもんな? being used?

My understanding was something like

"People try to attempt do things kindly... but well that's not necessary. To the level you want me to pay attention to you"?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97756/5010

Comment: I'm still not sure how it related? "You'd rather me be your partner?" In that example there is an adjective

Comment: Sorry, my link above was not really spot-on.

Comment: Is this a dialogue between two people, or does one person utter all these lines?

Comment: All of this is said by a single person

Comment: I don't quite follow the reasoning of the character, but I guess you're basically right. The third panel says "Oh well, (being kind) is unnecessary cuz you even want to be cared about by me".

Answer (score 2):

- This くらい is described in this question: [Help understanding a JLPT N3 conversation (～くらいだから)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47176/5010) Although だから is not explicitly used, the function of くらい is the same. That is, 俺に相手にされてえくらい is an extreme reason for 俺を怒らせたい.
- されてぇ is short for されたい, not されて(い)たい.
- I don't know this character, but the assumed background seems to be that everyone knows he is extremely short-tempered. くらい implies that just trying to get his attention is an outrageous action.
- 相手 refers to the person one is interacting with in a given situation, but "partner" is not an appropriate translation in a context like this.

So literally...

> 俺に相手にされてえくらいだもんな?
> (People normally never try to get my attention, but) it's even that you want to be dealt with by me...?
>
> (つまり)俺を怒らせてえんだろうが
> (That naturally means) you want to make me mad!

Or more naturally, "If you're going out of your way to get my attention, that means you're aiming to piss me off, huh?" or "Considering how much you want me to get my attention, you must be trying to anger me!"

Comment: One might add that da mon(o) at the end of a sentence is equivalent to da kara.